# Why is SQL Server returning a different order when using 'month' in 'where'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

I run a procedure call that calculates sums into table rows. First I taught the procedure is not working as expected, so I wasted half a day trying to fix what actually works fine.

Later I actually taken a look at the `SELECT` that gets the data on screen and was surprised by this:

```
YEAR(M.date) = 2016
--and MONTH(M.date) = 2
```

and

```
YEAR(M.date) = 2016
and MONTH(M.date) = 2
```

[image: Screenshot]

So the second example returns a different sorting than the first.

The thing is I do calculations on the whole year. Display data on year + month parameters.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to avoid this?

In my procedure that calls the `SELECT` for on screen data I have it implemented like so:

```
and (@month = 0 or (month(M.date) = @month))
and year(M.date) = @year
```

So the month parameter is optional if the user wants to see the data for the whole year and year parameter is mandatory.

Comment: You have ties. If you only order by a column that has ties, SQL Server is free to choose whatever order it wants for all of the rows that have the same value. If you want predictable sorting, make sure your ORDER BY can sort every single row, therefore you need to order by is naming enough columns so that the combination is unique, or unique enough to matter (e.g. `ORDER BY M.date, sumamount DESC` might be enough, but if there are ties with `sumamount` too, and this matters, you need to add a 3rd column).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are ordering by the date column.  However, the date column is not unique -- multiple rows have the same date.  The `ORDER BY` returns these in arbitrary order.  In fact, you might get a different ordering for the same query running at different times.

To "fix" this, you need to include another column (or columns) that is unique for each row.  In your case, that would appear to be the `id` column:

```
order by date, id
```

Another way to think about this is that in SQL the sorts are not stable.  That is, they do not preserve the original ordering of the data.  This is easy to remember, because there is no "original ordering" for a table or result set.  Remember, tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: Indeed, this solved my problem. I could also solve this by saving actual timestamps into the [date] field, but I can't do that for older records, so I put the [id] field into the order by. Thank you.